# sed command to replace a line

Tags: linux, sed

There is a file `sample.txt`. The contents of this file is

```
..some content...
  # bind-address = ":7086"
  # bind-address = ":8086"
```

I want to uncomment the line for port 7086 and replace the port also to 8888 so that final modified file would look like

```
..some content...
   bind-address = ":8088"
  # bind-address = ":8086"
```

I want to do it with the `sed` command. So what will be the exact command?

Comment: Does the line for port `7086` always contain `  # bind-address = ":7086"` or there could be some other string as well.

Comment: It always contains  '# bind-address = ":7086"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As confirmed in comments, the string always contains `# bind-address = ":7086"`. So to replace it just use `sed` search and replace option by hardcoding the strings.

```
sed -i 's/# bind-address = ":7086"/bind-address = ":8088"/' file2
```

Comment: @AshishDoneriya - No problem. Make sure to accept the answer so the question could be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
sed -i 's/#\(.*\)7086/\18088/g' file_content
```

Here every thing after `#`and before `7086`is grouped and then the entire line would be replace with `\1` (group 1 or say region 1 ) and your required port 8088

Comment: +1 Better option if the string between `#` and `7086` is not fixed. But in this case, OP confirmed that it is fixed. So it is safer to hardcode the string. Anyways good command.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1,/#/ s/#/ /' filename > temp1
```

replaces the 1st occurrence of the pattern with empty space.

then for changing the port number

```
sed 's/7086/8086/' temp1 > filename
```

Comment: What about the port change?

Comment: That's a direct sed change right. `sed 's/7086/8086/' filename`